# Yii : Automate timestamps in ActiveRecord models. Is it a bug?

Tags: timestamp, yii

I followed [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/10/how-to-automate-timestamps-in-activerecord-models/) to do automate timestamps in ActiveRecord models. The modified and created values are correctly saved into database. But when I try to retrieve the modified time and created time, **something** is wrong. Is it a bug?

```
    [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2956
        [title] => saved into database      
        [created] => 2011-10-26 16:16:30
        [modified] => CDbExpression Object
            (
                [expression] => NOW()
                [params] => Array
                    (
                    )
                [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                [_m:CComponent:private] => 
            )
    )
```

Bug fixed:

```
    $info->hits++;
    **$modified = $info->modified;
    $info->save(); //This will change modified to Now()
    $info->modified = $modified;**
```

Comment: Did you read the comments at the link?  Also, do you set the modified time on a new record?

Comment: There is actually a Behavior designed to handle timestamps if you want to avoid doing it yourself: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/CTimestampBehavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean you are trying to retrieve the value of modified in the same request that it is being saved?

In this case, since you (probably) set $this->modified=new CDbExpression('NOW()') in beforeSave event, then this is the value in modified field. In order to get the actual date you will need to retrieve it from the database by using findByPk (or some find method).

Usually this value is not needed in the same request when the model is being saved, but if so you can just use time() I guess.

Comment: Thanks. I did update the hits of thread and then render the model. So the modified is changed to "CDbExpression('NOW()')".